# i made first react app and when i upload it on github i only see blank page on github page

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages

hi so im trying to upload page made in react to github at start i ran into problem of it showing me only README file but i managed to solve that by following deployment  guide on [react website](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages) and that help well kind of, now i ran into other problem which is that github is just showing me  [blank page](https://giga4444.github.io/countries/) i don't understand why is it like this cuz i changed file and it shouldn't be empty and here is [git repository](https://github.com/giga4444/countries2) for non- npm build version of page and also here is [git repo](https://github.com/giga4444/countries) for the build version of page that is just blank, am i running in this problem cuz i used npm build wrong way? how do i fix it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found easier to use Netlify to upload websites.
I think if you are using only an html file you can just set the github pages with root and it shouldn't reuqire to use build run, I think the build command it is for projects done with frameworks/more complext. Try to do like that maybe it will work.

Comment: when i don't use build command and just upload it straight away my page is just README.md, i will look into Netlify if i didn't manage to solve this problem here how it looks like without using build command https://giga4444.github.io/countries2/